# how to append the error class next to textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I just want to ask on how to display error message next to textbox if the user doesn't enter anything and press submit required attribute should throw the desired error next to the textbox and not below it

Comment: what did you try to do and not worked?

Comment: You should show some code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the empty `input`s and add an error span next to it:

```
$("input").filter(function () {
  return $(this).val().trim().length == 0;
}).after('<span class="text-danger error">You need to fill this!</span>');
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").filter(function () {
    return $(this).val().trim().length == 0;
  }).after('<span class="text-danger error">You need to fill this!</span>');
});
```

```css
* {font-size: 10pt; font-family: Segoe UI;}
.error {background: #f99; border: 1px solid #f00; padding: 3px; color: #fff; font-size: 85%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="Filled" /><br />
<input placeholder="Not filled" /><br />
<input value="Filled" /><br />
<input value="Filled" /><br />
<input placeholder="Not filled" /><br />
<input value="Filled" /><br />
```